# make a div rotate, but keep its content fixed

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-animations

I'm trying do an arrow to point to a direction, chosen by a gamepad. I styled my arrow like this :
[A screen of my arrow, as an image is better than 1000 words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG9sG.png)

When an angle is given by the joystick, everything is rotating with this angle (`rotate` applied to `circle` class). Thus the tip of the black triangle is pointing to a direction. Pretty, isn't it ? :D

But you can see a number, in the middle. It's an important information (a PWM setting I'm sending over TCP, but not the subject here) And I want it to be in the center of the circle for... style ?

My issue is : I centered this number with a flexbox, then, when all the circle is rotating, the number is rotating too ! It's ugly ! How can I avoid this? :(

Please find the CSS and the HTML below :

```html
                <div class="cercle" id="fleche">
                    <div class="middle">
                        <p id="vitesse">1306</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="triangle">
    
                    </div>
                </div>
```

```css
            .cercle {
                order:0;
                border-radius: 50%;
                height: 80%;
                aspect-ratio: 1/1;
                background: linear-gradient(45deg, pink, red);
                display: flex;
                rotate: 0deg;
                transition: 350ms;

                .middle{
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    height: 92%;
                    width: 92%;
                    background-color: black;
                    align-self: center;
                    margin: auto;
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    align-items: center;
                    justify-content: center;

                }   

                .triangle {
                    width: 0px;
                    border-style: solid;
                    border-width: 20px;
                    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) black rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) ;
                    margin-left: 44.4%;
                    margin-top: -7.2%;
                    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    position: absolute;
                }

                #vitesse{
                    /*...*/
                }
            }
```

You probably guessed it, there is no critical issue, just aesthetic. I tried to apply an opposed rotation to this number, but the result is not satisfying (seems like "clipping".) I think the best option is to forbid the rotation of the number... by getting it out of the circles? But I've to keep it inside, if I want the number to dynamically stay in the center of the circle.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple idea without too much code:

```css
.box {
  --s: 15px; /* control the triangle size */

  width: 250px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: var(--s); 
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) content-box,
    linear-gradient(45deg,#fff,red); /* the gradient coloration */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset: 0 calc(50% - var(--s)) 50%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 var(--s),50% 0,100% var(--s),100% 100%, 0 100%);
  background: #000;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  rotate: 20deg; /* control the rotation here */
}


body {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">1350</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of two things:

1. An easy fix would just to rotate the text by the negative amount of whatever your circle is rotated. So if the input from the joystick is 80deg, you rotate #vitesse by -80deg.
2. The first method will work fine but its better to set your hierarchy to be more indicative of whats going on. I would separate the rotating element from the non rotating elements so that it would not be a parent of them, so when it rotates it will not rotate anything else

Answer (score 0):

you can essay this

```
`.cercle {
  order: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 80%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, pink, red);
  display: flex;
  transform: rotate(30deg); /* Rotate the .cercle element */
  transition: 350ms;
}

.middle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 92%;
  width: 92%;
  background-color: black;
  align-self: center;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.triangle {
  width: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) black rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  margin-left: 44.4%;
  margin-top: -7.2%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

#vitesse {
  /* Counter-rotate the paragraph to cancel out the parent's rotation */
  transform: rotate(-30deg); /* Counter-rotate by the same amount as .cercle's rotation */
  color: #fff;
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help !

As I said, I couldn't apply a counter rotate to the text, cause the text is twinkling in that case.
After a good sleep night, and reading @Yftach, the solution is simple ! I created another flex container, in which there is the circle and the text centered : The two are centered, but the circle is no longer a parent of the text (text isn't on the left of the circle cause I set `position: absolute`.) So the circle can rotate without causing the text to rotate ! :D.

```html
    <div class="gauche">
        <div class="cercle" id="fleche">
            <div class="middle">
            </div>
            <div class="triangle">
        
            </div>
        </div>
        <p id="vitesse">1306</p>
    </div>
```

```css
.gauche{
    order: 0;
    height: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    background-color: blue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;

    .cercle{
        /*unchanged*/
    }

    #vitesse{
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```